# Принять GET параметр в jsp

Tags: jsp, jstl

Как можно jstl-ом принять параметр var от перехода any.jsp?var=some

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы можете обратиться к нему используя объект `param`.

```
<c:if test="${not empty param.var}">
   // сделать что-то
</c:if>
```

Comment: да, спасибо, уже разобрался, через post запрос прекрасно принимает param.var. Наверное некорректно вопрос поставил. С прямыми ссылками будет проблема если столкнусь.